# Caching Image Uploads Across Page Loads with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Caching Image Uploads Across Page Loads with Rails
The Problem

Let’s imagine we have a form to create a BlogPost with a title, body, and thumbnail image, and we validate that all attributes are present. Something like this:

```
   <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div>
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :thumbnail %>
    <%= f.file_field :thumbnail %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Consider the following sequence of events:
A user fills in the body field, selects a thumbnail to upload, and submits the form.
The form renders again because the title is missing.
The user fills in the missing title and re-submits the form.
[image]

Uh oh! The validations fail because the image is missing!

The user now has to find the image they wanted to upload again, which is irritating. We would like to avoid making the user irritated.

The Solution: Image Caching

CarrierWave has great functionality for caching an uploaded file across form re-renders.

Under the file field, let’s add:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :thumbnail_cache %>
```

Be sure to add thumbnail_cache to attr_accessible in Rails 3, or your permitted params in Rails 4.

Let’s also add a preview so that the user can see the current attached image:

```
<%= image_tag(@post.thumbnail_url) if @post.thumbnail? %>
```

Now if a user submits the form with a missing title, their thumbnail image selection sticks around. Irritation avoided. Great success.
[image]

**It works fine...**

**but how to add value to  <%= f.file_field :thumbnail %>**

I have **No file chosen**

*I would like to have*  **thumbnail_cache - File name**

Comment: You cannot put value in the file field coz it has to be the whole path to the local file. If you have the whole local path to the file then you can set either by using js or rails.